# chrome sometimes caching webpack://scripts wierdly

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools, webpack

I use webpack as a module bundler

I have map files enabled

In chrome my original script files come from a special webpack resource
[image]

I'm not too sure what causes it but sometimes an old version of a script gets cached. The actual new code is still updating correctly but the version referenced by the map is out of date. This means line numbers don't match anymore and I cant see any code changes (eg super annoying).

It seems to eventually just fix itself but makes me sad in the meantime.

**Has anyone else had similar issues/have any ideas of how to sort it out?**

It seems to be isolated to chrome (if I go to another browser the correct version is loaded)

I have tried:

- Deleting the map file and regening it
- Empty cache and hard reload
- Manually navigating to the file in chrome (correct version is returned but it remains out of date when refed by map file)

Comment: Yeah, I had this issue too.
Standart cache cleaning doesn't solve it. The only solution I've found is to clear the cache this way: Go to Network tab in devtools, press right button and click "clear browser cache".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked out that this was caused by the actual map file being cached.

If you open the map file in a new tab and hard reload it, the source is all updated correctly

Its probably a bug in chrome that this is not reloaded with the dev tools disable cache setting or the pages hard reload.

Comment: Besides manually refreshing the page to see your updated source map, did you figure out a solution?  Were you using hot reloading (hot module replacement)?  I'm having the problem that you describe with hot-reloading (the code itself is injected into the page but the source maps are out-of-date).  It happens with both "source-map" (where a separate source map file is generated) and "eval-source-map" (where the source map is embedded into the source file).

Comment: @JasonFrank sadly the only way I've solved it was to manually refresh the map file. I wasn't using hot loading at the time but its the same problem. I'm not sure if its limited to chrome or to webkit. If its a real pain it might not be as bad in another browser.

Comment: this is still a nightmare in chrome

Comment: the only other way to solve this problem is by reinstalling Chrome